# TFS Build Definition - Can you add this to source control?

Tags: tfs, build

I would like to add my Build Definitions to TFS Source Control.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Not really, no. If you're trying to track changes to your build definitions, you can use a couple of new commands in the latest releast of the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f). The first compares two build definitions:

```
tfpt builddefinition /diff
```

This one exports a build definition's configuration to a text format, which you could then check into version control.

```
tfpt builddefinition /dump
```

Comment: bah if I run it from my source directory it says it can't load `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow` if I run it from `c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0` it says *Unable to determine the source control server*

Comment: @Maslow Same error here.. (on 2 different machines w/ VS2013 + TFPT)

Comment: I realise this is a really old question and answer, but for anyone coming here now as I did, using TFS v15, I was able to export the build definitions as json and save them in source control. There is also the option to import the json.

Answer (score 0):

Another option via powershell

https://gist.github.com/jstangroome/6747950

which basically uses c# types so should be easy enough to make into a linqpad or c# console app (or winforms or wpf)

used assemblies

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll