# TFS / Visual Studio Online build definition backup

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there any way to get hold of a VSO build definition file, so it can be backed up / added to source control?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247497/tfs-build-definition-can-you-add-this-to-source-control) question but tfpt doesn't appear to support connection to VSO (maybe I'm doing something wrong?)

```
tfpt builddefinition /dump <myproj> /collection:https://<myorg>.visualstudio.com/

TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://<myorg>.visualstudio.com/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's looking for the CollectionUri, not the server Uri, have you tried: `/collection:https://<myorg>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection`

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, this is the command that worked for me: `tfpt builddefinition /dump "<projName>\<buildDefName>" /collection:https://<myOrg>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection /filepath:<pathToBackup>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to jessehouwing, and some further web searches, the following works:

```
tfpt builddefinition /dump "<projName>\<buildDefName>" /collection:https://<myOrg>.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection /filepath:<pathToBackup>
```

If you get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo
ken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

You need to copy **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll** from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools
```

(thanks to http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/richarderwin/2014/09/11/CompareTFSBuildDefinitions.aspx)